# TypeError:undifined is not an object (evaluating 'arr.length') react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Hello every body i am  learning to create react native animation when scroll and when i add const headerHeight, i got error like this,
i follow a tutorial on youtube,in video not got an error, but in my script i got 
[error bangsad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR9VS.jpg)

### full code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, ScrollView, Image, Animated} from 'react-native';
console.disableYellowBox = true;
const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT=120;
const HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT=70;
const PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT=80;
const PROFILE_MIN_HEIGHT=40;
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0,HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT-HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
      ouputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
      extrapolate:'clamp'
    })
    return (<View style={{
      flex:1
    }}>
      <Animated.View style={{
        top:0,
        left:0,
        right:0,
        height:headerHeight,
        position:'absolute',
        backgroundColor:'skyblue'
      }}></Animated.View>
      <ScrollView style={{
          flex: 1
        }}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent:{contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}])}>
        <View style={{
          height:PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT,
          width:PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT,
          borderRadius:PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT/2,
          overFlow:'hidden',
          marginTop:HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT-PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT/2,
          borderWith:4,
          borderColor:'white',
          marginLeft:11
        }}>
          <Image source={require('./assets/me.jpg')} style={{
            borderWith:4,
            borderColor:'white',
            height:PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT,
            width:PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT,
            borderRadius:PROFILE_MAX_HEIGHT/2,
          }}/>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={{
            fontWeight:'bold',
            fontSize:18,
            paddingLeft:11
          }}>Nagacoder</Text>
        </View>

      </ScrollView>
    </View>)
  }
}
```

here is my react native version

> ```
> "native-base": "2.4.2",
> "react": "16.3.1",
> "react-native": "0.55.2",
> ```

dustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: We miss lot of information to help you. where is the code called ? don't think that just declaring a variable would break your code. Please give us more info.

Comment: Please include the relevant section(s) of your source code.

Comment: see my code was update,

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use outputRange, like this:

```
ouputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
```